# When using "zh" for cc_lang_pref on a video that accepts Chinese, the closed captions show english

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

**Steps to reproduce**

- Test video https://www.youtube.com/embed/1wmlKb-UIac
- Updated test video, link including query parameter **cc_lang_pref** set to "zh": https://www.youtube.com/embed/1wmlKb-UIac?cc_lang_pref=zh&cc_load_policy=1
- The above video should show Chinese closed captions. Instead, it shows English closed captions.
- Here is a url for Spanish (es) that works: https://www.youtube.com/embed/1wmlKb-UIac?cc_lang_pref=es&cc_load_policy=1

**NOTE:** if you manually select Chinese (simplified/traditional) subtitles, it works fine.

Comment: Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before posting

Comment: Ali - unfortunately, your comment doesn't shed any further light on my issue... Not sure how much more concise I could be here.

Comment: Hi, what I meant was, you shared no code what so ever, are you using iframe in HTML with Youtube Embeds or actually using the Youtube API? Where are you trying to show the video? A good question will give you the right answer.

Comment: I have updated the issue to be more clear on the steps to reproduce. There is no code here, this is simply using the YouTube iFrame player api via query parameters on the video link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zh is not a valid culture code, hence why the subtitles are defaulting to English. Valid Chinese culture codes are:

- zh-Hans (Chinese Simplified)
- zh-Hant (Chinese Traditional)

So back to your issue, if you use the following YouTube embed urls it works:

- https://www.youtube.com/embed/1wmlKb-UIac?cc_lang_pref=zh-Hans&cc_load_policy=1 (Chinese Simplified)
- https://www.youtube.com/embed/1wmlKb-UIac?cc_lang_pref=zh-Hant&cc_load_policy=1 (Chinese Traditional)

Comment: Yes, I ultimately figured this out. However, YouTube needs to update their documentation appropriately. It currently refers to http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php and indicates to use the ISO 639-1 code.